# Ajax in Yii - type: post

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

I have one question:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var num = 6;
    $("#ajaxBtn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:    "<? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('section/show'); ?>",
        type:   "POST",
        data:   {"num":num},
    ...
});
```

must this construction send $_POST['num'] to my controller's action or not?

thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: sterswift did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$_POST['num']` (or, more appropriately, `Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('name')`)  will be available to your controller action.

I 'm not so sure what you mean by using "must" though.

Comment: thanks for answer, sorry for my english ) but it doesn't work. here is the fragment of action    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
                $this->layout = false;
                $criteria->offset = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam("num");
                $sections = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
            }

Comment: @sterswift: Well, what does `var_dump(Yii::app()->getRequest()->getParam('name'))` say? Perhaps `num` is out of scope in your client-side code? (you can test this by hardcoding directly `"num": 6`)

Comment: var_dump() said 'NULL'; and even when the data equals "num": 6, getParam('name') is still 'NULL'